# Как указать путь к js в Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

проблема в том, что я начал создавать аутентификацию в своём приложении, но не могу указать путь для родного app.js чтобы было выпадающее меню.
app.blade.php - тот самый путь:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Выпадающее меню:

```
<a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
   {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Не понял в чем проблема, но в script-е другой путь, в webpack - другой.

Comment: Должно выпадать меню когда нажимаю на ссылку с id="navbarDropdown", но меню не выпадет, я не до конца понимаю как работает asset и как правильно указать путь до файла со скриптом

Comment: asset идет в папку public, все js, css, картинки должны хранятся там. А в папке resources/js, хранятся vue файлы.

Comment: Понял. Но у меня в папке public/js в файле app.js все родные скрипты laravel. Когда я делал аутентификацию, справа сверху есть выпадающее меню с именем юзера(при нажатии выпадало окошко "выйти"), я указал в вопросе, но когда часть файла родной аутентификации я перенёс в другую вьюху, то выпадающее меню перестало работать

Comment: @Narek, а по пути localhost/home выпадающее меню работает

Comment: А app.css подключаешь?